# How much it is safe to store and reuse the iterator values of map in another map?

Tags: c++, stl

How much it is safe to store and reuse the iterator values of map in another map?

```
map<BYTE,vector<connections*>*> mconnections1;//sorting connections based on device key.

for (map<Device*,vector<connections*>>::iterator it=m_eip.m_mvpConnections.begin(); it!=m_eip.m_mvpConnections.end(); ++it)
        mConnections1[it->first->DEVICE_KEY]=&it->second;

for (map<BYTE,vector<connections*>*>::iterator it=mConnections1.begin(); it!=mConnections1.end(); ++it)
{

for(unsigned int i=0;i<it->second->size();i++) it->second->at(i)->Write(&fp);

}
```

Comment: If `connection` is a polymorphic base class I can see the need for using pointers for that. Otherwise I don't really see that need. And *very* seldom is there any need whatsoever to have pointers to containers (like a pointer to a vector).

Comment: And iterators are very tightly bound to the container that returned them. You can not use an iterator created by one instance of a container with another instance (even if the container type is otherwise equal). If that's what you're asking?

Comment: If the key in `m_eip` gets removed, that address you stored in `mconnections1` is now invalid.  Looks like you should consider `std::unordered_map<BYTE, std::shared_ptr<vector<connections*>>>` if you don't know who really owns the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The iterators returned by `std::map` are invalidated by various operations, if you don't call these operations then you can store the iterators, if you do they will become invalid and using them will be undefined behaviour.

Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and look for words like "iterators invalidated" in the method descriptions.